# Getting SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused when running upgrade command for Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, database

I am getting the following error when running the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command in my Magento 2.3 instance:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

I can connect to the database using the `mysql -u root -p` and can run commands there without any issue. So I've determined that this is an issue with Magento's connection to the DB. I have gone in and changed the env.php setting from localhost to 127.0.0.1 with no luck. Recently we did have a DNS change, but I'm not sure if that would effect the database. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `env.php` file if your db credentials  are correct.
Check if `dbname` has the right database that you are using, `username` and `password` are the ones you use to log into MYSQL.I would suggest you keep  `'host' => 'localhost'`.

Comment: All of the DB creds are correct. The site is functioning properly with the exception of that setup:upgrade command.

Comment: Then check your permissions for your magento installation, probably something is misconfigured.

Comment: I have checked permissions and they are set correctly. Where else should I look?

Answer (score 0):

Running the `php bin/setup:config:set` fixed the issue.